# What 3d technology should I use for my browser application?

Tags: flash, 3d, xna, webgl, unity-game-engine

I need some little 3D rendering in my browser application. Unfortunatly the Internet Explorer 8 is not going to support WebGL, Canvas 2D or SVG. And the Windows XP users can't install the IE9 (which supports at least Canvas 2D).

What do you think about Plugin-based alternatives?

- I mean Silverlight with XNA 3D seems not to be supported any longer.
- Flash has a bad reputation if I ask Apple.
- What do you think about Unity3D?
- Are there others?

I need some Arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be not a right question to ask here but anyway here are my 2 cents:

1. **Silverlight** seems dead. I haven't seen any site using it for a long time. I doubt a big percent of general users have the plugin installed.
2. **Flash** completely dominates desktops but is not supported on mobiles (if you haven't heard Adobe discontinued mobile flash player development even for Android devices).
3. **Unity3d** has really cool IDE. You can create your little 3D scenes in just hours. But plugin support is not good and it doesn't work on mobile devices. What's cool is Flash export in Unity3d 3.5 wich allows you to publish your little 3D content as SWF.
4. **WebGL** is a good solution too but as you said it's not supported everywhere. But iOS devices will be able to show your content.
5. **Java** applets are dead too. Nobody likes them and non-developers sometimes don't even have plugin installed.

I'd go for Flash and Stage3d. There are decent 3d libraries like Alternativa3D and Away3D. Or you could use Unity3D and flash export. This solution will work for common people. Of course visitors with iPad will not see your 3D stuff.

You could think of using Flash for desktops and WebGL for mobile devices. Depends on how complex your little 3D elements are.

Answer (score 1):

If your target is web browsers on desktop machines, your best bet is flash. I am developing a game right now that uses Flare3D, a commercial 3D library for flash, and I have only good things to say about it so far.

If your target is web browser on mobile, your best bet is to wait another year until 3D is common on all mobile devices. Its not yet.

If you target is mobile devices using installed apps, then your best bet is Unity3D. It is easy to deploy and runs 3D on both iOS and android.

Unity 3D makes a good case as being best for online web too, as it can export to flash, now. But it still has the drawback that devices that don't support flash, also don't support unity as a browser plugin.

Just to drive the point home, the ONLY approach for mobile devices is to have a native app. But probably within a year the mobile browsers will support some flavor of OpenGL ES2. However, if windows phone makes inroads by that time, all bets are off.